# django-admin: How to redirect to URL after one Object save?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Django Signals to Trigger Code once the user is created i am saving additional data on another model class, it's getting triggered but it's not redirecting to additional data object page.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Customers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pincode = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    mobile = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def create_customer(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']:
            customer_profile = Customers.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

    post_save.connect(create_customer, sender=User)
```

and here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Customers
from django.shortcuts import redirect

admin.site.register(Customers)

class Customers(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        return redirect('/admin/app/customers/add/')

    def response_change(request, obj):
        return redirect('/admin/app/customers/add/')
```

Tired looking for the answer but nothing works, please correct me here.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are registering your admin configuration. Refer to [Django docs on the register decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator) for more information. The syntax is to decorate your function with `@admin.register(<model>)` or if you want to manually register the model admin configuration then `admin.site.register(<model>, <model admin>)`.

I would recommend changing `class Customers(admin.ModelAdmin):` to `class CustomersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):` or something similar to stop the namespace clash.

See example below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Customers
from django.shortcuts import redirect


@admin.register(Customers)
class CustomersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        return redirect('/admin/app/customers/add/')

    def response_change(request, obj):
        return redirect('/admin/app/customers/add/')
```